# org-protocol not responding

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-protocol

## Description

I use [`org-capture` extension](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension) which had been working great for about 6 months.

I have trouble making `org-protocol` work from Firefox since 8/1/19. When hitting the extension button in FF, the page is captured (I got a gray background with "captured" message) but nothing happens in Emacs. This used to work fine until then.

I run Emacs 27.0.50 on Ubuntu
16.04 with org-mode 9.2.5 (and Firefox 68.0.1).

## Diagnosis

1. My org-protocol config in init:

```
(require 'org-protocol) ; call for org-protocol
(server-start)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.local/share/applications/org-protocol.desktop/") ;path to org-protocol
```

My `org-protocol.desktop` file is set and `mimeinfo.cache` is up to date.

2. My `org-capture-templates` have not been edited and other templates (not called through the FF
   extension) work fine. The templates used by org-protocol are:

```
("L" "Web link" entry (file+headline org-default-notes-file "Web")
 "** [%:description]%? \nSource: [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured: %U")
("p" "Web quote" entry (file+headline org-default-notes-file "Web")
 "** [%:description]%? \nSource: [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured: %U \n#+BEGIN_QUOTE\n%i\n#+END_QUOTE")
```

3. The FF extension runs well and sends capture instructions (the grey background *ie* 2nd snapshot
   on [org-capture extension](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension)) according to FF console:

[1]

```
Capturing the following URI with new org-protocol:  org-protocol://capture?template=p&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediaonfire.com%2Fblog%2F2017_07_21_org_protocol_firefox.html&title=Firefox%20and%20org-protocol%20URL%20Capture&body=emacsclient%20-n%20%22org-protocol%3A%2F%2F%2Fcapture%3Furl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fduckduckgo%252ecom%26title%3DDuckDuckGo%22
```

4. Org-protocol executes neatly on my other latptop running Emacs 24 (from Ubuntu repo) with similar
   config.
5. Conclusion

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what the problem is. I found some inspiration on [this page](http://www.mediaonfire.com/blog/2017_07_21_org_protocol_firefox.html) and tried to run the test suggested. Adapted to my config, the test is:

[2]

```
emacs-snapshot "org-protocol://capture?template=p&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediaonfire.com%2Fblog%2F2017_07_21_org_protocol_firefox.html&title=Firefox%20and%20org-protocol%20URL%20Capture&body=emacsclient%20-n%20%22org-protocol%3A%2F%2F%2Fcapture%3Furl%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fduckduckgo%252ecom%26title%3DDuckDuckGo%22"
```

with [1] object.

When Emacs is closed, a
frame opens with an empty buffer with mini-buffer saying `file is write protected`.

I think this test drives me in the right direction to solve my problem but maybe this has nothing to
do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem.

I clarified my understanding of
`emacs-snapshot` *vs* `emacsclient` according to the manual 
[here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html#Initial-Options) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options).

When running [2] (see question), nothing would happen in current Emacs frame (same as when hitting the extension button in FF).

I then tried the same command replacing `emacs-snapshot` by `emacsclient`: I got the message `emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?` although `server-start` is set in my init.

In the mean time, I realized I had made some clean up on my init and was wondering I might have
messed up org-protocol set up. No problem on this side since org-protocol runs smoothly on laptop B
with the same `init.el`. Laptop B runs same org version in different Emacs (Emacs 25.2.2, Org 9.2.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 with FF 68.0.2).

I thought I should try with the same Emacs version on two laptops. I checked how different were my Emacs install on laptops A *vs* B which made me realize I had both `emacs24` and `emacs-snapshot` installed on laptop A. I first removed `emacs24` (I always run `emacs-snapshot`) and HURRAY! connection between FF extension and `emacs-snapshot` through MIME is back.

The verbose command speaks for itself:

`:~$ sudo apt autoremove emacs24
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances

Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  emacs24 emacs24-bin-common emacs24-common emacs24-common-non-dfsg emacs24-el
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 5 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Après cette opération, 104 Mo d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] 
(Lecture de la base de données... 458358 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de emacs24 (24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1) ...
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/bin/emacs-snapshot » pour fournir « /usr/bin/emacs » (emacs) en mode automatique
Remove latex-cjk-thai for emacs24
remove/latex-cjk-thai: purging byte-compiled files for emacs24
Remove dictionaries-common for emacs24
remove/dictionaries-common: Purging byte-compiled files for flavour emacs24
Remove latex-cjk-common for emacs24
remove/latex-cjk-common: purging byte-compiled files for emacs24
Remove emacsen-common for emacs24
emacsen-common: Handling removal of emacsen flavor emacs24
Suppression de emacs24-bin-common (24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1) ...
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/bin/ctags-snapshot » pour fournir « /usr/bin/ctags » (ctags) en mode automatique
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/bin/ebrowse-snapshot » pour fournir « /usr/bin/ebrowse » (ebrowse) en mode automatique
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/bin/emacsclient-snapshot » pour fournir « /usr/bin/emacsclient » (emacsclient) en mode automatique
update-alternatives: utilisation de « /usr/bin/etags-snapshot » pour fournir « /usr/bin/etags » (etags) en mode automatique
Suppression de emacs24-el (24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1) ...
Suppression de emacs24-common (24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1) ...
Suppression de emacs24-common-non-dfsg (24.4+1-2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
:~$`

That does not explain though why this would have worked great for 6 months.

Here some r/emacs threads that I found inspirational and helped me to solve my (stupid yet annoying) problem.

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3hvmka/making_use_of_orgprotocol_to_have_a_bookmarking/

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/bi2lwp/does_emacs_have_the_capability_of_capturing/

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/cnzj7d/org_mode_update_broke_orgcapture/

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ai7hf0/does_anyone_here_still_use_orgprotocol/

https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/akazos/orggrasp_browser_extension_for_orgcapture/

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem while using Brave, and what worked for me was making a small change to `~/.local/share/applications/org-protocol.desktop`.

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Name=org-protocol
Exec=emacsclient -n %u
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=System;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/org-protocol;
```

##### emacsclient -n %u

The change was to use `emacsclient -n %u`.  The original example from **[sprig/org-capture-extension](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension#under-linux)** did not use `-n`, but when I added it, org-capture-extension started working reliably again.  The `-n` makes emacsclient immediately return, and that seemed to help.

Prior to this, it had worked fine for years without the `-n`.  I don't know if the breakage was Brave's fault or org-mode's fault, but at least it works for me again.  Maybe this will help someone deal with this mysterious problem.